# Django Rest Framework Session vs Token Authentication

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF, and I've enabled Session Authentication so that I can view the browseable API in my browser. In my mobile app, i'm using token authentication. I'm just curious, how does session authentication differ from token authentication in this context? It seems to me that they are more or less the same because with session based auth, a session id instead of a token id is stored in a cookie and used in the same way. Can anybody explain it better?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sessions and cookies are mainly meant for browsers where the browser will take care of sending the cookie with every request to the server. This why the CSRF protection is only enabled by default for session authentication. On the other hand, token authentication will most probably used with non-browser clients where it stores the auth token and send it with each request in header. This token is not necessarily obtained by exchanging the credentials for a token similar to what happens in session authentication. There can be a use case where an admin generates these tokens and hands it to some other system client that will invoke your API, and clearly this client does not have to have a username and password to exchange it for a token.